# What's the strongest way to tie drywall into Rock-Lath/plaster with an embedded mesh?

Tags: drywall, doors, plaster

I'm replacing our utility door that goes out to garage, and want to know the best way to tie the new drywall in with the old Rock-Lath/plaster.

Usually I just put a backer board in, but with this big cut I've hit the mesh that they used to reenforce the wall edges.

I was thinking of leaving the mesh since it reenforces the corner, and slipping a plywood backer board under the joints.  Is there a better way?

[image: Close up of mesh]
[image: Whole frame]

Comment: Putting plaster back up, would be a lot easier and probably have a better bond at the joints.